# ARKit how to place object on plane surface?

Tags: unity-game-engine, arkit

I'm new to ARKit and I imported **Unity ARKit Plugin** from the Unity Assets Store, I loaded **UnityARKitScene** to the scene, and replaced the **hitcube** GameObject with my prefab asset.
I can run the project on my device, but the model which I imported can be placed not only on surfaces but on the 'air' too.

Is there anything that I need to change to make place the model on plane surfaces only?

Thank you.

Comment: When I was confronted with the same question I chose to use the plane detection mechanism from the Apple ARKit Example. 

Download at: https://github.com/gao0122/ARKit-Example-by-Apple

Comment: You can try to use only `ARHitTestResultTypeExistingPlaneUsingExtent` as an acceptable result of `HitTest`. It seems to be the most accurate type of hit result.

Comment: @Kingalione but the project in the git repo is not unity right?

Answer (score 0):

In UnityARHitTestExample.cs just change the following code

```
// prioritize reults types
ARHitTestResultType[] resultTypes = {
    ARHitTestResultType.ARHitTestResultTypeExistingPlaneUsingExtent,
    // if you want to use infinite planes use this:
    //ARHitTestResultType.ARHitTestResultTypeExistingPlane,
    ARHitTestResultType.ARHitTestResultTypeHorizontalPlane,
    ARHitTestResultType.ARHitTestResultTypeFeaturePoint
};
```

To this

```
// prioritize reults types
ARHitTestResultType[] resultTypes = {
    ARHitTestResultType.ARHitTestResultTypeExistingPlaneUsingExtent,
    // if you want to use infinite planes use this:
    //ARHitTestResultType.ARHitTestResultTypeExistingPlane,
    //ARHitTestResultType.ARHitTestResultTypeHorizontalPlane,
    //ARHitTestResultType.ARHitTestResultTypeFeaturePoint
};
```

For more info check https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arhittestresult.resulttype